# We roll a fair die until a $5$ appears. What is the expected value of the minimum value rolled?

Tags: probability, expected-value

> Question: Given a fair dice, we roll until we get a $5.$ What is the expected value of the minimum value rolled?

Answer is $\frac{137}{60}.$

There is a similar question [asked in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2796838/54398) but I do not understand the method used by Henry.

In particular, if we let $X$ be the minimum value rolled up to and including $5$, then 
$$E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^5 xP(X=x) = 1 \times \frac12 + 2 \times \frac16 + 3 \times \frac1{12}+4 \times \frac{1}{20}+5 \times \frac15 = \frac{137}{60}.$$
It seems that we are using the fact that 
$$P(X=x) = \frac{1}{x(x+1)}.$$

> I do not understand how to obtain the equation above.

Comment: Your expected value calculation is all wrong for this problem.  Note you might get a $5$ on the first roll... or second... or 10000000th....

Comment: @David G. Stork perhaps you can shed some light on how to compute the expectation above?

Comment: What is the problem you have with Oscar's argument in that old thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $X$ is not the minimum value rolled **before** obtaining a $5$, it is the minimum value rolled **up to and including** the first roll that comes up $5$, so that $X=5$ is possible.

The event $X=5$ means that $5$ comes up before any of $1$, $2$, $3$, or $4$ (we don't care about $6$). Since each of the five numbers is equally likely to come up first,
$$P(X=5)=\frac15.$$

Now suppose $1\le x\le4$. Now the event $X=x$ means that, among the $x+1$ numbers $1,\dots,x,5$, the number $x$ comes up first, and $5$ second. Thus we have
$$P(X=x)=\frac{(x-1)!}{(x+1)!}=\frac1{(x+1)x}\text{ for }1\le x\le4.$$

Comment: We *do* care about six.  What is the minimum for the very possible sequence $666665$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The minimum is $5$, the same as if $5$ came up on the first roll. What's your point?

Comment: In calculating an expectation, we need to sum over the probabilities of the different conditions, e.g., $65$, $665$, $6\cdots65$.  Each has a different probability so we have to sum over all of these.  Right?

Comment: My point is that $X=5$ means that the first $5$ comes before the first $1$, the first $2$, the first $3$, and the first $4$, so the probability is $1/5$. It doesn't matter if the first $6$ comes before or after the first $5$, since we're taking the minimum.

Comment: I do not understand the last equality for $P(X=x)$. Why do both numerator and denominator depend on factorial?

Comment: @Idonknow The denominator $(x+1)!$ is the total number of (equally likely) orders in which the $x+1$ values $1,2,\dots,x-1,x,5$ can appear, and $(x-1)!$ is the number of those orderings in which $x$ comes first and $5$ comes second. Alternatively, $\frac1{x+1}$ is the probability that $x$ is the first of those values to appear, and $\frac1x$ is the conditional probability that $5$ is the next to appear given that $x$ was the first.

Comment: +1. Very clever and insightful answer.

Answer (score 6):

Assume that a $5$ is first seen on roll $n$.
$5$ is the lowest seen with $n-1$ $6$s then one $5$.
$4$ is the lowest seen with $n-1$ $4$s and $6$s, but not all $6$s then one $5$.
$3$ is the lowest seen with $n-1$ $3$s, $4$s, and $6$s, but not all $4$s and $6$s then one $5$.
$2$ is the lowest seen with $n-1$ $2$s, $3$s, $4$s, and $6$s, but not all $3$s, $4$s, and $6$s then one $5$.
$1$ is the lowest seen with $n-1$ $1$s, $2$s, $3$s, $4$s, and $6$s, but not all $2$s, $3$s, $4$s, and $6$s then one $5$.
$$
\begin{array}{c|l|l}
\text{lowest}&\text{chance with $n$ rolls}&\text{sum over $n$}\\
\hline
5&\,\left(\frac16\right)^{n-1}\frac16&\frac15\\
4&\,\left[\left(\frac26\right)^{n-1}-\left(\frac16\right)^{n-1}\right]\frac16&\frac1{20}\\
3&\,\left[\left(\frac36\right)^{n-1}-\left(\frac26\right)^{n-1}\right]\frac16&\frac1{12}\\
2&\,\left[\left(\frac46\right)^{n-1}-\left(\frac36\right)^{n-1}\right]\frac16&\frac16\\
1&\,\left[\left(\frac56\right)^{n-1}-\left(\frac46\right)^{n-1}\right]\frac16&\frac12
\end{array}
$$
Expected value $=5\cdot\frac15+4\cdot\frac1{20}+3\cdot\frac1{12}+2\cdot\frac16+1\cdot\frac12=\frac{137}{60}$

Comment: I am not getting it. Why do we subtract for 6, then 4,6; then 3,4,6 etc etc... ? Because of overcounting since we already included the number in the previous calculation?

Comment: When the lowest is $5$, we have rolled $(n-1)$ $6$s and then a $5$; thus, $\left(\frac16\right)^{n-1}\frac16$. When the lowest is $4$, then we have rolled $(n-1)$ $4$s and $6$s (but not $(n-1)$ $6$s), then a $5$; thus, $\left[\left(\frac26\right)^{n-1}-\left(\frac16\right)^{n-1}\right]\frac16$. When the lowest is $3$, then we have rolled $(n-1)$ $3$s, $4$s, and $6$s (but not $(n-1)$ $4$s and $6$s), then a $5$; thus, $\left[\left(\frac36\right)^{n-1}-\left(\frac26\right)^{n-1}\right]\frac16$. etc.

Comment: Still not getting the extact meaning of the second component in the bracket. 

Like, in the sequence 46464465 we get three 4s, three 6s and then the 5. The probability of getting the sequence of 4and6 in that way is $(1/6)^6$. then again, in 3463463465 i have a sequence of three 3s,4s, and 6s and the chance of that happening is $(1/6)^9$

Comment: The number of ways to get seven $4$s and $6$s is $2^7$. However, this also counts seven $6$s, which doesn't give $4$ as the lowest, so we need to subtract that off: $2^7-1^7$. The number of ways to get nine $3$s, $4$s, and $6$s is $3^9$. However, this also counts nine $4$s and $6$s, which doesn't give $3$ as the lowest, so we need to subtract those off: $3^9-2^9$.

Comment: oh ok now I see it, thank you very much robjohn!

Comment: But now I am not getting the sum over n. How do you get 1/5, 1/20 , 1/12 etc etc

Comment: Sum the geometric series in the middle column for $n\ge1$ to get the right column.

Comment: what does it mean? how should I sum?

Comment: If you are looking at this question, I assume you are familiar with [how to sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) a [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). For example, in the row for $n=3$, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\color{#C00}{\left(\frac36\right)^{n-1}}-\color{#090}{\left(\frac26\right)^{n-1}}\right]\frac16=\left[\color{#C00}{\frac1{1-\frac36}}-\color{#090}{\frac1{1-\frac26}}\right]\frac16=\frac1{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

A start:

If you get a $5$ on the *first* roll, then

$${\cal E}[x] = 5$$

If you get a $5$ on the *second* roll, then

$${\cal E}[x] = \frac{\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 i\right) + 6}{5} = \frac{16}{5}$$

If you get a $5$ on the *third* roll, you write out all $25$ possible die outcomes:  $11$, $12$, ... , $43$, $44$,..., $64$, $66$ and count the number of such outcomes in which $1$ is the minimum value appearing; count the number of outcomes where a $2$ is the minimum value appearing, up to $6$ being the minimum value

You have to get a general formula for ${\cal E}[X]$ for a given number of rolls (before a $5$ appears).  This value is defined for arbitrary number of rolls... even 10000000.

Then you find the *probability* of getting each number of rolls before a $5$ appears.  The probability it appears on the *first* roll is of course $1/6$.  The probability it appears on the *second* roll is the probability

Comment: Why would obtain a $5$ makes expectation undefined? Wouldn't we get 5 as minimum value in this case?

Comment: OK... a special case.  I'll amend my "solution."

Comment: Where does the '6' come from in the 'if you get a 5 on the second roll' formula? Shouldn't that be '5'?

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the minimum is $X\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ can be found as follows:

The probability of rolling a sequence of length $k$ using numbers from the set $\{X,X+1,\dots,6\}-\{5\}$ is $\left(\frac{6-X}{6}\right)^k$.  Similarly, the probability of getting a sequence with values in $\{X+1,\dots,6\}-\{5\}$ is $\left(\frac{5-X}{6}\right)^k$. So the probability of a sequence of length $k$ with all elements in $\{X,\dots,6\}-\{5\}$ and at least one instance of $X$ is $\left(\frac{6-X}{6}\right)^k-\left(\frac{5-X}{6}\right)^k$.  The probability of rolling a $5$ right after this sequence is $1/6$.

We sum over $k$ to find the probability of getting a sequence of any length with minimum $X$.  This works out to $$P(X)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{6-X}{6}\right)^k-\left(\frac{5-X}{6}\right)^k = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{1}{X} - \frac{1}{1+X} = \frac{1}{X(X+1)} & \text{for } X=1,2,3,4\\
        \frac{1}{X} = \frac{1}{5} & \text{for } X=5\\
        \end{array}\right.
$$ Which is what we wanted.

Comment: @bof Good catch.  The sum evaluates differently for $X=5$.  I have amended accordingly.